# Kotlin: generic method and for loop asking for iterator()

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

This is a simple generic method,and passing the values the args in for loop is causing an error saying:

> for-loop range must have and iterator() method

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)
    val charA: CharArray = charArrayOf('a','b','c','d')

    printMe(arr)
    printMe(charA)

}

fun <T>printMe(args: T){
   for (items in args){
        println(items)
    }
}
```

how do i make it iterate throught the values for both `char[]` and `array`

Comment: This is an unfortunate legacy of Java arrays. Use lists instead - they are basically the same, but with correct inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for-loop in Kotlin works by convention, looking *statically* for an operator member named `iterator` which must return something that can be iterated, i.e. something that has in turn operator members `next` and `hasNext`.

`operator` modifier on such members is required to specify that the member is to satisfy some convention, namely the iteration convention.

Since `args` is of type `T` and there is no `iterator` member in every possible type `T`, it can't be iterated readily.

However you can provide an additional parameter to `printMe`, which knows how to get an iterator out of an instance of `T`, and then use it to obtain an iterator and iterate it:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)
    val charA: CharArray = charArrayOf('a','b','c','d')

    printMe(arr, IntArray::iterator)
    printMe(charA, CharArray::iterator)

}

fun <T> printMe(args: T, iterator: T.() -> Iterator<*>) {
    for (item in args.iterator()) {
        println(item)
    }
}
```

Here `T.() -> Iterator<*>` is a type which denotes a [function with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). Instances of that type can be invoked on `T` as if they were its extensions.

This snippet works because the iterator returned has itself an operator extension function `Iterator<T>.iterator() = this` which just returns that iterator, thus allowing to loop through the iterator with a for-loop.

Comment: This is neat, but I don't like the binding of the type into the call site. It feels like this is too similar to something like `printMe(arr.iterator)` where `printMe is given by `fun <T> printMe(iterator:Iterator<T>)`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson You can also call printMe as `printMe(arr, { iterator() })`. I agree in this case you can just pass an iterator itself, but sometimes you may need to instantiate it in `printMe` several times or do something else with `args`.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a little bit subtle.

The key problem is that variable `arr` is of type `IntArray` and `IntArray` is not derived from `Array`. Similarly while `IntArray` has an `iterator()` function it does not implement `Iterable<>`.

The same occurs for for `CharArray` variable.

In fact `IntArray` and `CharArray` and `Array<T>` don't seem to have any common base class or interface other than `Any`. So you're either stuck passing an object and doing a typecheck in `printMe`, or using overloading.

A type-checking version would look like

```
printMe(args:Any) {
   if(args is IntArray) {
      for(item in args) {
         println(item)
      }
   } else if (args is CharArray) {
     for(item in args) {
        println(item)
     }
   } else {
     println("Not an IntArray or a CharArray")
   }
}
```

Overloading would look like this

```
printMe(args:IntArray) {
  for(item in args) {
    println(item)
  }
}

printMe(args:CharArray) {
  for(item in args) {
    println(item)
  }
}
```

IMO overloading is the better option since you can't end up passing an object you cant handle by mistake.

Comment: overloading may be best option, but i'm practicing and i want to know how things works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler does not know you are passing an `Array` and `T` can be of any type.

One way to fix this would be using `is` operator:

```
fun <T>printMe(args: T){
    if(args is Array<*>) {
            for (items in args) {
                println(items)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work since an IntArray and CharArray are noth not an Arrays.